# itertools.chain return a unexpected iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

To my understand, Python [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is designed to chain several iterators.

When the first generator contains `['a/a.jpg', 'a/b.jpg']` and the second generator is an empty generator, the expected output is `['a/a.jpg', 'a/b.jpg']`.

But the code below gives me a confusing result `['a/b/a.jpg', 'a/b/b.jpg']`:

```
import itertools
import os

jpeg_paths = iter([])
# jpeg_paths = []

walk = [("a", ["a.jpg", "b.jpg"]), ("a/b", ["a.txt"])]

for dirpath, filenames in walk:
    # select image files
    jpg_filenames = filter(lambda name: str.endswith(name, "jpg"), filenames)
    # generate absolute path
    image_fullpath = map(lambda name: os.path.join(dirpath, name), jpg_filenames)

    jpeg_paths = itertools.chain(jpeg_paths, image_fullpath)
    # jpeg_paths += image_fullpath

a = list(jpeg_paths)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was the `iterable` is executed with the `last` `dirpath` which is the `a/b`. Not the the `itertools` always returns `iterator`, it won't be executed until it is iterated over.

So to associate the `dirpath` with each `iteration` in the `for` loop, we could use a simple `function` like `mapfunc`. So the resulting code will be like,

```
import itertools
import os

jpeg_paths = []

walk = [("a", ["a.jpg", "b.jpg"]), ("a/b", ["a.txt"])]

def mapfunc(filenames, dirpath=None): # `dirpath` will be associated with each function object
    return map(lambda name: os.path.join(dirpath, name), filenames)


for dirpath, filenames in walk:
    # select image files
    jpg_filenames = filter(lambda name: name.endswith("jpg"), filenames)
    # generate absolute path
    #break
    image_fullpath = mapfunc(jpg_filenames, dirpath=dirpath) # associate the `dirpath` to each `function` object
    jpeg_paths = itertools.chain(jpeg_paths, image_fullpath)

print(list(jpeg_paths))
```

or you could, exhausts the `iterator` on each iteration like,

```
image_fullpath = tuple(map(lambda name: os.path.join(dirpath, name), jpg_filenames))
```

So it will associate the `dirpath` that moment to the `jpg_filenames` call.
But that will keep all the `objects` in `memory`, and if the thing you want to walk is quite large, it is not a good idea :)

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean by *gets exhausted*. In the original code, you mean `image_fullpath` is exhausted? I don't think it's exhausted since it can return a `tuple` when applying `tuple` on it.

Comment: Yes clearly mentioned in the documentation:

In [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), result is always a list.

While in [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), result is an iterator.

Comment: So if you don't call list or tuple as done by han solo, the value of the dirpath variable be update to the latest value `a/b`, and on printing out the corresponding list, you wll find the latest dirpath.

Comment: @Mohit I understand. But are there another solution to keep `image_fullpath` always a `generator` to avoiding storing the full-size `list` (or `tuple`) in the memory?

Comment: @HuangYuheng I have updated the code to make it work with `iterator`s only